# AWS Amplify + Angular + SSO Login 'Invalid state'

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement SSO with angular, aws-amplify and amazon cognito user pools. I have a default congnito user pools login working good, but I have problems with SSO Login with Google.

I have a custom ui for default cognito user pools login. But I'm using hosted UI for SSO Login.

I currently use federatedSignIn method from Aws Amplify:

```
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify'

Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google });
```

But after I enter my Google credentials I get an error:
`An error was encountered with the requested page: 'Invalid State'`

The user is actually added to the user pool. But I can not continue using my app because I'm stuck on the Invalid State page.

I was searching for weeks and didn't found any reasonable solution.
I already checked the redirect uri everywhere — its correct and matches on AWS Cognito, on GCP app and in my app properties.
I also have the google identity provider enabled in User Pool -> App Integration -> Client -> Hosted UI -> Identity providers.

Here is my request that is generated by aws-amplify:[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3thO.png)

Also I can see following network requests in the developers console: [Request 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiejo.png) [Request 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKaOX.png) [Request 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYrYc.png)

I can't find any short and simple examples using AWS SDK instead of AWS Amplify. It will be also a valid solution using AWS SDK with angular for SSO Login.